# Number counter animation preloader window on load Javascript Html CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create a number counter animation on my portfolio website. I have some jquery code from my old website that transitions from preloader to website when fully loaded.

```
    <script>
  $(window).on('load', () => {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut(1800, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
    </script>
```

How can i add the number counter animation and add a side up transition?
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to be more specific

Comment: Basically I want to do something like this https://aristidebenoist.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

1. Declare count.
2. Decrease count value.
3. Based upon counter value `slideUp` your `div` and `remove` counter span.

Example:

```js
$(window).on('load', () => {
  let count = 3;
  function ShowCounter() {
    if (count > 0) {
      $("#spnNumber").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("#spnNumber").text(count);
        $("#spnNumber").fadeIn();
        count--;
      });

    } else if (count == 0) {
      $("#preloader").slideUp();
      $("#spnNumber").remove();
      clearInterval(interval);

    }

  }
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    ShowCounter()
  }, 1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='preloader'>Loading ... </div>
<span id='spnNumber'><span>
```